# Regex to match a path, excluding the final directory. Perl error "search pattern not terminated at -e"

Tags: regex, bash, shell, perl, unix

Say I have a directory path

```
 /abc/de/fgh/i/jk
```

And I just want to match

```
 /abc/de/fgh/i/
```

How would I do this? I have tried:

```
 (\/.*\/)*
```

In https://regexr.com/ and it seems to do the trick.

However, when I try:

```
 path="/abc/de/fgh/i/jk"
 sliced=`echo $path | perl -pe '(\/.*\/)*'`
```

I get the error:

```
 Search pattern not terminated at -e line 1
```

Is there a better way to do this besides perl? What is wrong here anyway to give a perl error? Is my regex even correct here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a coreutil to do this, `dirname`:

```
path="/abc/de/fgh/i/jk"
sliced=`dirname "$path"`
```

However, it also removes the trailing `/`. If you, for whatever reason, need it, just append it to `sliced`:

```
sliced=`dirname "$path"`/
```

Be sure to quote `$path`; it won't work with paths with spaces in them if you don't.

Your Perl program isn't working because you haven't put any regex operators around it. It ignores the first `\` since it isn't in a string or regex, then finds the `/`, which begins a regex. Since there's no unescaped `/` to end it, it gives you that error. You probably want something like `s/(\/.*\/)*.*/$1/`, which should erase everything after the last `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed`, but match what you want to *remove* (rather than what you want to keep):

```
echo $path | sed 's,[^/]*$,,'
```

Outputs `/abc/de/fgh/i/`

The regex matches all non-slash chars at the end and replaces them with nothing, removing them.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Parameter Expansion ?

```
echo "${path%/*}/"
```